# How to display a list of members from a twitter list with just their Avatar

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, list, twitter

I've been trying to figure out a way to list the profile images of all the members from a particular list.

I can fetch statuses from the API URL

```
 $.ajax({
  url: "https://api.twitter.com/1/lists/statuses.json?slug=stringed-chaos&owner_screen_name=darkpsy",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  jsonpCallback: "listTweets"
});

function listTweets(r) { 
console.log(r);
var output = '<ul>';

$.each(r, function(key, val) {
    var text = r[key].text;
    var thumbnail = r[key].user.profile_image_url;
    var name = r[key].user.name;

    output += '<li>';
    output += '<img src="' + thumbnail +'" alt="Photo of ' + name + '">';
    output += '<div>' + text + '</div>';
    output += '</li>';      
}); //go through each tweet
output += '</ul>';
```

When I change the API URL to the GET lists/members URL (as stated in the [official twitter doc here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/lists/members) )
I'm unable to pull any information (undefined).
I can parse the statuses.json just fine, but the members.json returns nothing

code as follows :

```
    $.ajax({
  url: "https://api.twitter.com/1/lists/members.json?slug=stringed-chaos&owner_screen_name=darkpsy",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  jsonpCallback: "listTweets"
});

function listTweets(r) { 
console.log(r);
var output = '<ul>';

    $.each(r, function(key, val) {
        var text = r[key].text;
        var thumbnail = r[key].profile_image_url;
        var name = r[key].screen_name;
            output += '<li>';
        output += '<img src="' + thumbnail +'" alt="Photo of ' + name + '">';
        output += '<div>' + text + '</div>';
        output += '</li>';      
    }); //go through each tweet
    output += '</ul>';
    $('#tweetlist').html(output);}`
```

Would appreciate any kind of help, as the twitter API docs don't seem too friendly and neither did I find anything online to address this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter's members list API returns data in different format from the statuses API. The data you are looking for is contained under `users[]`. Here's a fixed solution:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.twitter.com/1/lists/members.json?slug=customers&owner_screen_name=vijaysales",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success : function(data) {listTweets(data["users"]);}
});

function listTweets(r) {
    var output = '<ul>';

    $.each(r, function(key, val) {
        var text = r[key].text;
        var thumbnail = r[key].profile_image_url;
        var name = r[key].screen_name;


        output += '<li>';
        output += '<img src="' + thumbnail +'" alt="Photo of ' + name + '">';
        output += '<div>Photo of ' + name + '</div>';
        output += '</li>';      
    }); //go through each tweet
    output += '</ul>';
    $('#tweetlist').html(output);
}
```

I changed the callback from `jsonpCallback` to `success()` because `jsonpCallback` didn't seem to work too well on jsFiddle's latest version of jQuery.

Try it on jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vCA4F/ and check out the structure of the returned JSON on [jsonviewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://api.twitter.com/1/lists/members.json?slug=customers&owner_screen_name=vijaysales).

Comment: Worked a treat! really appreciate the prompt response, had been rattling my brains on it since quite a while. :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.twitter.com/1/lists/statuses.json?slug=customers&owner_screen_name=vijaysales",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(r) {
      listTweets(r);
    }
  });
  function listTweets(r) {
    var output = '<ul>';
    $.each(r, function(key, val) {
      var text = r[key].text;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(r[key]));
      var thumbnail = r[key].user.profile_image_url;
      var name = r[key].screen_name;
      output += '<li>';
      output += '<img src="' + thumbnail +'" alt="Photo of ' + name + '">';
      output += '<div>' + text + '</div>';
      output += '</li>';      
    }); //go through each tweet
    output += '</ul>';
    $('#tweetlist').html(output);
  }
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tweetlist"></div>  
</body>
</html>
```

You can use `success` method. I fixed issue about profile_image_url.

**UPDATE**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.twitter.com/1/lists/members.json?slug=customers&owner_screen_name=vijaysales",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(r) {
      listTweets(r);
    }
  });
  function listTweets(r) {
    var output = '<ul>';
    $.each(r.users, function(n, user) {
      var text = user.status ? user.status.text : '';
      var thumbnail = user.profile_image_url;
      var name = user.screen_name;
      output += '<li>';
      output += '<img src="' + thumbnail +'" alt="Photo of ' + name + '">';
      output += '<div>' + text + '</div>';
      output += '</li>';      
    }); //go through each tweet
    output += '</ul>';
    $('#tweetlist').html(output);
  }
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tweetlist"></div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response Matt, I'm able to fetch statuses.json with the code I posted as well. The problem is getting results from members.json. :]